# Macbook Air boot menu defaults to external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display

Took a while to figure out why the screen stays black during boot, but I eventually found that the boot menu and apple logo are by default going to an external monitor. I have tried to fix this by resetting the default display in system preferences, SMC and PRAM resets, but to no avail. I'm at a loss as to what is causing this to happen, and can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found issue to be in the display assembly. I assume something on the control board got shorted or is not functioning properly, causing EFI to not recognize the screen at boot.

Answer (score 0):

Dragging the status bar (*in Display Settings*) to the screen you want as default worked for me! :)

[image]

Comment: I've done this multiple times, did not resolve the issue.

Comment: When your Macbook lid is open, does your Macbook monitor also work or only the external monitor?

Comment: When booted, the internal display works fine, it's during the boot that the image only shows on external monitor. Cannot get into boot menu either.